# How to update android app with hidden icon

Tags: android, icons, hide, android-launcher

I use this code for hiding icon:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class); 
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

It works fine, but when I try to update my application, I get this error:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "../..main.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=../.main.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {../..main.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

How can I hide icon and still available application update (without uninstall/install in a manual way)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by update? Are you updating your app by just clicking the "Run" button in Android Studio and waiting for it to be built and installed?

Comment: Update to new version or from Android Studio or from apk. In the case of Android Studio I get error that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: The error you have mentioned is not about updating the app. It is about not being able to start the activity you have disabled which makes sense. The install command is `adb install [-r] your.app.id` and it most likely was successful in your case. You can verify it by updating and checking the app versionCode and versionName. One of the ways to do so is command `adb shell pm dump your.app.id | grep 'version'`

Comment: If `adb install` command was indeed successful, you can safely ignore the MainActivity launch failure.

Comment: @Amaksoft you are right. I must be more specific. Installing process work good for me, but in starting activity I get error.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your use-case, when do you hide the icon, how do users launch you app and so on?

Answer (score 0):

This is a design problem I think. You need to prevent MainActivity getting launched when it is disabled. If you are forced for some reason to start your MainActivty after updating, just enable your MainActivity first. You can set MainActivity enabled state to false in the Manifest and make it enabled whenever you need for example in onCreate method of the application class, in a service or in a broadcast receiver. Disabling MainActivity in the Manifest probably prevent it to be launched by default and might be the thing you need. It is all based on your need of how and when you want your MainActivity to get disabled and enabled again. For a final comment as you probably know an app doesn't need an activity - with action main or not - to get started.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` from the `Activity` and there will be no launcher icon - while it still can be launched, due to `android.intent.action.MAIN`. If you really need a launcher icon, which can be hidden & shown, simply add one proxy `Activity`, which has no other purpose than providing the launcher and then start the actual `Activity`... so that one still can start it directly, no matter if that proxy `Activity` had been disabled, whether or not.